# How to create oblique text (UILabel) in IB?

Tags: iphone, uilabel, uifont

How to create oblique text (UILabel) in IB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the label in IB, click the gray button next to "Font" label in Attributes Inspector (Cmd-1) and select the font.
[image]

Comment: The problem remaining. I use tahoma , it has not oblique.

Comment: How do you expect to show text in oblique Tahoma if it doesn't exist? A font either exists or doesn't exist, in the latter case you cannot draw text with it.